# What Skill/Build is this?

Tags: grim-dawn

Five seconds into [this video](http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/256667904/movie480.webm?t=1470085252), there is a character performing a laser skill which seems to wipe the entire map.

- What skill is this?
- Are there build guides for this character?
- Can this character be played without the DLCs?

Comment: looks like something from the arcanist class, though i dont remember the exact name

Comment: This seems awfully broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be Albrecht’s Aether Ray with Disintegration, which is an Elementalist build. You can find a build guide for this character [here](http://www.grimdawn.com/forums/showthread.php?t=30239) and a skill tree [here](https://grimcalc.com/build/SXKF4E).

[image: Albrecht’s Aether Ray with Disintegration]